# Admob ads in Emulator

Tags: emulation, admob, ads

Is admob blocked my account when I check ads in Emulator.

How invalid clicks made in Emulator ?

Pls help me

Comment: I think might be another reason for blocking admob account... How much impressions/clicks you did generate per day? (average)

Answer (score 4):

If you do that so often. 
to avoid that use test ad.

`AdRequest req = new AdRequest();
req.addKeyword("game"); 
req.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);`

Add a test device before load ad. You also may add you phone as test device. look in logcat, adView activity will send you an info abut how to run only test ads on your phone

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Android emulators get automatically configured as Admob test devices, so you don't need to call `addTestDevice()`.

However, if you also want to test your ads on a real device, you will need to add it as a test device. This can be done either through Admob UI(`Settings` -> `Test Devices` -> `Add test device`) or programmatically, as [described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10133769/11105280) by @Jova.

Docs: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices